# MoveFocus skips controls

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

I want to allow users to navigate within a control using the Arrow Keys.

Users should still be able to navigate horizontally with the Tab and Shift + Tab controls but I want them to be able to navigate vertically (which may skip controls that would be focused if they navigated horizontally).

If I use the `MoveFocus` method on `UIElement` what seems to happen is that certain controls are skipped such as buttons and editable combo-boxes.

Does anyone know why this is? These controls are focused normally using TAB but FocusDirections of Up/Down/Next seem to skip the controls. If I take a look at `PredictFocus` it seems to report that Buttons should be focusable in this way but not editable combo-boxes.

Demo code below:
XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Focus.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="FocusStyle">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Stroke="CadetBlue" StrokeThickness="2" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="txtBox1" Width="75"/>
                <TextBox Width="200"
                         Name="txtBox1"
                         Margin="5"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource FocusStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="button1" Width="75" />
                <Button Width="200"
                        Name="button1"
                        Height="25"
                        Margin="5"
                        Content="Hello"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource FocusStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="txtBox2" Width="75"/>
                <TextBox Width="200"
                         Name="text2"
                         Margin="5"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource FocusStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="comboBox" Width="75"/>
                <ComboBox Width="200"
                         Margin="5"
                         Name="comboBox"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource FocusStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="txtBox4" Width="75"/>
                <TextBox Width="200"
                         Margin="5"
                         Name="txtBox4"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource FocusStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="comboBox2" Width="75"/>
                <ComboBox Width="200"
                         Margin="5"
                          IsEditable="True"
                         Name="comboBox2"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource FocusStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Margin="3" Text="{Binding FocussedControl.Name, StringFormat=Focused Control: {0}}" />
            <TextBlock Margin="3" Text="{Binding PredictedFocusControl.Name, StringFormat=Predicted Focus {0}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.Xaml.cs :

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Focus
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public IInputElement FocussedControl
        {
            get { return (IInputElement)GetValue(FocussedControlProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FocussedControlProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FocussedControlProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("FocussedControl", typeof(IInputElement), typeof(MainWindow));

        public DependencyObject PredictedFocusControl
        {
            get { return (DependencyObject)GetValue(PredictedFocusControlProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PredictedFocusControlProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty PredictedFocusControlProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PredictedFocusControl", typeof(DependencyObject), typeof(MainWindow));

        protected override void OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            FocussedControl = e.NewFocus;
        }

        protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
            if (e.Key == Key.Down)
            {
                var success = (FocussedControl as UIElement).MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Down));
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(success);
                PredictedFocusControl = (FocussedControl as UIElement).PredictFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Down);
            }
            else if (e.Key == Key.Up)
            {
                var success = (FocussedControl as UIElement).MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Up));
                PredictedFocusControl = (FocussedControl as UIElement).PredictFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Up);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that the problem with the button was not handling the PreviewKeyDown event. However, the editable combobox is still not focusable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by setting IsTabStop=true in the ComboBox even though Tab was working to focus on the control:

```
<Window x:Class="Focus.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="FocusStyle">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Stroke="CadetBlue" StrokeThickness="2" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Width="75" Content="txtBox1" />
                <TextBox Name="txtBox1"
                         Width="200"
                         Margin="5"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource FocusStyle}" />
                <TextBox Width="200"
                         Margin="5"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource FocusStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Width="75" Content="button1" />
                <Button Name="button1"
                        Width="200"
                        Height="25"
                        Margin="5"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource FocusStyle}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Content="Hello" />
                <TextBox Width="200"
                         Margin="5"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource FocusStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Width="75" Content="txtBox2" />
                <TextBox Name="text2"
                         Width="200"
                         Margin="5"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource FocusStyle}"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <TextBox Width="200"
                         Margin="5"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource FocusStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Width="75" Content="comboBox" />
                <ComboBox Name="comboBox"
                          Width="200"
                          Margin="5"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          VerticalAlignment="Top"
                          FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource FocusStyle}">
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Item1" />
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Item2" />
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Item3" />
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Item4" />
                </ComboBox>
                <TextBox Width="200"
                         Margin="5"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource FocusStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Width="75" Content="txtBox4" />
                <TextBox Name="txtBox4"
                         Width="200"
                         Margin="5"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource FocusStyle}" />
                <TextBox Width="200"
                         Margin="5"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource FocusStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  >
                <Label Width="75" Content="comboBox2" />
                <ComboBox Name="comboBox2"
                          Width="200"
                          Margin="5"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          VerticalAlignment="Top"
                          IsTabStop="True"
                          FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource FocusStyle}"
                          IsEditable="True" />
                <TextBox Width="200"
                         Margin="5"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource FocusStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Margin="3" Text="{Binding FocussedControl.Name, StringFormat=Focused Control: {0}}" />
            <TextBlock Margin="3" Text="{Binding PredictedFocusControl.Name, StringFormat=Predicted Focus {0}}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by palying with `FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"  Focusable="True"` now it works:

```
 <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="txtBox1" Width="75"/>
            <TextBox Width="200"
                     Name="txtBox1"
                     Margin="5"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource FocusStyle}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Focusable="True"  FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True">
            <Label Content="button1" Width="75" />
            <Button Width="200" Focusable="True" IsTabStop="True" 
                    Name="button1"  FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"
                    Height="25"
                    Margin="5"
                    Content="Hello"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource FocusStyle}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="txtBox2" Width="75"/>
            <TextBox Width="200"
                     Name="text2"
                     Margin="5"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource FocusStyle}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="comboBox" Width="75"/>
            <ComboBox Width="200" Focusable="True"
                     Margin="5"  IsTabStop="True" 
                     Name="comboBox"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource FocusStyle}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="txtBox4" Width="75"/>
            <TextBox Width="200"
                     Margin="5"
                     Name="txtBox4"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource FocusStyle}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"  Focusable="True">
            <Label Content="comboBox2" Width="75"/>
            <ComboBox Width="200" Focusable="True"
                     Margin="5" IsTabStop="True" 
                      IsEditable="True"
                     Name="comboBox2"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource FocusStyle}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Margin="3" Text="{Binding FocussedControl.Name, StringFormat=Focused Control: {0}}" />
        <TextBlock Margin="3" Text="{Binding PredictedFocusControl.Name, StringFormat=Predicted Focus {0}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Can't tell you why...

Comment: It's not down to the FocusScope or making the StackPanel focusable. The button gets focus once you add e.Handled = true to the OnPreviewKeyDown method. The combobox can be focused once IsTabStop = true (as you've done here). I suspect that the issue is with the control template for an editable combobox that relies on the IsTabStop to set whether the control can be navigated to as just using Tab worked fine.